# Consume SOAP protocol web service using PFX in VS 2017 or C#

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2017, pfx

We have to consume SOAP protocol based web service using PFX in VS 2017 or C#.

We installed the PFX in chrome and we are able to get WSDL.

In Visual Studio 2017, we are not able to add reference. When we try using the code below we get 500 error

```
HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://xxx/services/xx?wsdl");

//SOAPAction  

Req.Headers.Add(@"xxx");
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\xx\xx.pfx", "abc");

Req.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

//Content_type  
Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
Req.Accept = "text/xml";

//HTTP method  
Req.Method = "POST";
```

Please help us on how to add the reference in VS 2017 or how to consume it from runtime code

Cheers,
Kiran

Comment: Can you please add the error you are getting while adding service reference through VS ?

Comment: Did you install PFX in under local user OR you installed it under Local Machine ?  If it is under local machine VS should be able to generate proxy.

Comment: Hi Manoj, After adding the certificate to local machine i could move ahead. Thank you so much

Comment: I am glad it worked for you.  I have added this as answer, you can mark it as answer to conclude on this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check if your certificate is under "Local User" or it is under "Local Machine".

If it is under "Local User", please import certificate under "Local Machine" so that it can be used by Visual Studio.